# Inverting a change of coordinates to express a quantity in terms of another

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm sorry the title may have been a little vague, but I will do my best to be as specific as possible below.

Consider the following: $(x,y) = G(u,v) = (\sin(u^2v),\cos(v^2u))$. Then, we have that the determinant of the Jacobian of $G$ is: $|DG(u,v)| = -3(uv)^2\sin(u^2v)\cos(v^2u)$, (Wolfram Alpha confirms this).

So what I am trying to do is find is the determinant of the Jacobian of $G^{-1}(x,y)$. At first, I tried to use implicit differentiation but it got messy very fast so I gave up. Right now what I'm trying to do is finding the $|DG(u,v)|$ in terms of $(x,y)$. So far, I have $\sin(u^2v)=x$ and $\cos(v^2u)=y$ and the scalar factor $-3$, I can just divide out but I run into a problem with $(uv)^2$. I'm not sure how to go about expressing that in terms of $(x,y)$. Does anyone know of any general techniques that may help in situations like this?

That might sound a bit confusing but essentially what I am trying to do is expressing $(uv)^2$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have some hiccups with your notation. It should read:

$$G(u,v) = (\sin(u^2v), \cos(v^2u)) = \begin{pmatrix} x(u,v) \\ y(u,v) \end{pmatrix}$$

Then the jacobian is given by:

$$\textbf{Jac}(d_{(u_0,v_0):=p_0}) = \begin{bmatrix} G_u(p_0) & G_v(p_0)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(p_0) & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}(p_0) \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}(p_0) &\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}(p_0) \end{bmatrix}$$

By the inverse function theorem, if we assume that $\textbf{Jac}(G(p_0))$ has rank $2$ then for some neighborhood of $p_0$ we have $G$ is a local diffeomorphism and $\textbf{Jac}(G^{-1}) = (\textbf{Jac}(G))^{-1})$. For a $2 \times 2$ matrix, the formula for the inverse matrix is simple.

$$\textbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \textbf{A}^{-1} = \frac{1}{\textbf{det}(A)} \begin{bmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: My apologies, I meant to write the **determinant** of the Jacobian, thank you for pointing that out. The according edits have been made.

Comment: I made an appropriate edit. In your case $A = \textbf{Jac}(G(p_0))$.

Comment: I see, that makes perfect sense. Thank you!